# how to hide authorization bearer in a rest call?

Tags: rest, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory

We are working on a web app that makes rest calls to office 365. In the process, we get an app-only access token from azure active directory after providing necessary details. Using this access token, we get access to  the resources of all the users present in the active directory at the same time  do various outlook operations(rest calls!!). Anyone would be able to view these requests and responses using applications like fiddler or other web debuggers.This is a vulnerability that can be exploited to make calls to the server by anyone who can use  the access token which is openly visible.

things can be clearly put forth using the following images:-[image]

[image]

Our obvious question would be, how can such a scenario be avoided and how to secure our rest call, it is to be taken that access token is a must to reach office 365 or else operations cant be executed? please help !!

Comment: make the call over SSL??

Comment: Are you concerned about the possibility of token getting misused by the users of your app or someone sniffing the traffic on user's browser?

Comment: hey you got my point, i'm worried about it being misused by the users of my app!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about the fact that your users may misuse the token, one thing you could do is have all the requests route through your server instead of making REST API calls directly from the browser. At all times you can keep the bearer token on the server. Your users would call your API and then your API (which are running on your server) would call Office 365 APIs on behalf of the user using that token.

However you need to consider the scenario that the user is authenticated/authorized against their Office 365 and the token would not allow them to do any operation they are not allowed to. They simply can't take that token and issue any arbitrary request they don't have permission to.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone would be able to view these requests and responses using
>   applications like fiddler or other web debuggers

Yes, on the local machine - But the local user presumably is authenticated to make this operation...
In the same way you can capture your credit card information locally with Fiddler when you submit a payment form on a website...

The call is (or at least should be) made over HTTPS which encrypts it end-to-end - therefore won't be visible to people 'sniffing' the network.

Comment: thanks for the answer alex, but im worried about it being misused by the users of my app !!

Comment: also: it is not so much visible to anyone on the local machine but to anyone "in" the same browser so unless your browser is under control by other parties (which means you're beyond salvage) you're safe and the token is not leaked to anyone else but you

Comment: wrt. to the comment: the token allows the user to retrieve information that they're entitled to and that they're seeing displayed in their browser; that is not a problem; the token is "scoped" for each user individually

Comment: actually, in our problem, the access token is valid for all the users belonging to that active directory!!(specific active directory),http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2015/05/23/developers-guide-to-auth-with-azure-resource-manager-api/    thanku for the help though apppreciate it :D